# Cloud Run partially sets environment variables via Github Actions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run

I am playing with Github Actions and Cloud Run to automate my tasks.
I have set up repository on Github and prepared two workflows.
One for DEV and other for.. let's call it PROD environment.

Workflow deploys and run container with variables that are hardcoded:

```
- name: Deploy to Cloud Run
  run: |-
    gcloud run deploy ${{ env.SERVICE }} \
      --region ${{ env.REGION }} \
      --image gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{  github.sha }} \
      [...]
      --set-env-vars "X=testvar1" \
      --set-env-vars "Y=testvar2" \
      --set-env-vars "Z=testvar3" \
```

The problem I am facing is that dev environment works fine.
Whenever I trigger action for DEV it ends successfully, cloud run service is green and I can request my app on GCP.

When I am deploying literally the same on a prod environment, this step above fails.
When I debug more on this I go to the Variables & Secrets tab on Cloud Run instance for this failed service and there these env variables are missing. When I will add them manually via GCP console and redeploy it service works fine.

This should be done automatically as on the dev environment.
What is more when I trigger github action again for prod it replaces docker image and these manually set by me env variables are gone and I have to set them manually via condole again.

No additional security configs are made. This is just simple express app made in NodeJS.
Everything is literally the same when it comes to github workflows (yaml files), Dockerfile is also the same, GCP project too.

What might be the cause for that?

Comment: Have you checked Cloud Logging to see if there is any other information regarding the failed deployment?

Comment: Are you sure that your command isn't truncated with your are in production environment?

Comment: What are you using to set the value of said environment variables? Is it possible that they're not empty per-se but are being set to a empty/null value by the declaration you're making?